# objective-c writeToFile Doesn't on iPad, Does on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ipad, simulator, writetofile

I've seen the explanation that writeToFile doesn't work with non-objects,
however, this snippet shows there is a serious gap in what works on the iPad device
and how the simulator works.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOne = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Thing One", @"Thing Two", @"Thing Three", nil];
[arrayOne writeToFile:@"myLocalMovieMetaData-v11" atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"cancelNowButton Test Metadata File Written.");  
NSMutableArray *arrayTwo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"myLocalMovieMetaData-v11"];
NSLog(@"arrayOne: %@",arrayOne);
NSLog(@"arrayTwo: %@",arrayTwo);  //this prints on simulator but not the device.
```

Answer (score 3):

The application only has permission to write to its Documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLocalMovieMetaData-v11"];
```

Then use:

```
[arrayOne writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem. (You beat me to it by a few seconds.) To the OP, check the root of your hard drive. You'll find that the "myLocalMovieMetaData-v11" file has been created there.